# Tensorflow: saving SavedModelBundle model from Java

Tags: java, scala, tensorflow, save

Is it possible to save a SavedModelBundle from Java API?

My use case is that I would like to

1. Load existing `SavedModelBundle`
2. Assign new values for some Variables (by calling assign-op already defined in the graph)
3. Save the model again

Steps 1. and 2. I can do but I can't figure out how to do step 3.

Any way to achieve this

(I would like to do this in Java instead of Python because my whole application is in Java (Scala) so side-stepping to Python will add lot of complications.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API to save the Tensorflow model in JAVA environments.

Basically, in Java environments, you can only load the existed freezed Tensorflow model that you can't add new variables or modify the value in variables.

Step2, what you said is that you assign new values to java variable not Tensorflow model's variable.

In many case, build the model using the Python and freeze the model (the output file is "***.pb" in general), then using the model in Java.

Comment: It's possible to modify values in Java API by defining assign-operator in the graph and then calling this assign-operator from Java. This way the variables do get updated.   In step 2. I am referring the TF-variables not Java-variables.

Comment: Oh, I miss understood of it.

Comment: There is no official Tensorflow API for overwrite the PB file.
But, Tensorflow protocol buffer is written by "proto3" rules. 
You might find the other way to modify the values from site below.
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial